# FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity which I can start from Launcher . I have made some changes to Navigation bar so that i can start the same activity from navigation bar also.

But the expected behavior is that the activity should not start again if it is already on top of stack so I used [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) as flag. But it does not seam to work. I know that we can also achieve it specifying the `launchmode`  as `singleTask`. But i dont want to use that as I may be starting some 3rd party apps from navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
launchMode:singleTop
```

in the definition of your activity in the manifest? e.g.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

Comment: I don't remember what the problem was :)